# Are there any rules for spaceships in D20?

Tags: d20-system, vehicles

Aside from the D20 versions of *Star Wars*, which are different enough that they can't be used in combination with many normal D20 products like *d20 Mecha*, are there any books that have rules for creating and using spaceships in the D20 family?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the D20 Future line includes Open Game Content (OGC) starship rules.

You can get the official [Starships SRD in charmingly-2000s Rich Text Format](https://www.wizards.com/d20/files/msrd/FutureStarships.rtf) direct from Wizards of the Coast, or you can get them in convenient, futuristic HTML from a variety of online D20 Future SRD repositories, such as these: [Starships at *D20 Resources*](http://www.d20resources.com/future.d20.srd/starships/); [Starships at *DM Reference*](http://dmreference.com/MRD/Future/Starships.htm).

However, the combat rules included are considered fairly underwhelming (imagine normal D&D 3.5 combat, but you're in an endless empty room with no cover or other reasons to manoeuver and your choices are often limited to moving or shooting), and you might find [fan-made replacements](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?180050-d20-Future-Starship-Combat-that-doesn-t-make-me-cry-myself-to-sleep) more interesting to use along with the rest of the OGL rules.

Answer (score 5):

Besides d20 Future, there was also a d20 Traveller edition which had [a bunch of first and third party support including extensive starship oriented products](http://index.rpg.net/display-search.phtml?key=system&value=T20&sort=system,systemversion). Even large tracts of the main T20 Traveller's Handbook were devoted to starship design sequences.

The d20 Traveller game itself wasn't great, I'll be honest. [Here's a full review I wrote for RPG.net](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/10/10077.phtml). But the starship rules were more Traveller-inspired than the main system which was a pretty bad d20 adaptation.